# Export jquery created html table in a function to an excel file via the borwser

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

I have collected a whole lot of data from a page using jQuery and stored them in variables, and then I'm passing those variables to a function where I am trying to dynamically create a table, then once done export that csv file that when prompted through the browser I can save locally.

I have taken it this far below, but I cant seem to find the right way to action the create the excel file with the table which is selected by the id wrapped around the table.

I'm wondering if I can get some help with advice on am I on the right path, and if someone could help me get it over the finish line.

```
function exportStaffProfileExcel(profileTitle,profileDepartment,profileLocation,profileTelephone,profileEmail,profileBiography) {
    var table = "";
    table += "<table>";
    table += "<tr><td colspan='2'>Name : " + 'Work!' + "</td></tr></table>";
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
    var base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    var format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    var toExcel = $(table).html();
    var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || '',
        table: toExcel
    };
    newWindow = window.open(uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
    return newWindow;
    //window.open(uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something working, and hopefully its a good option:

```
function exportStaffProfileExcel(profileTitle,profileDepartment,profileLocation,profileTelephone,profileEmail,profileBiography) {
    var table = "";
    table += "<table>";
    table += "<tr><td colspan='2'>Name : " + 'Work!' + "</td></tr>";
    table += "</table>";
    
    // Get table HTML content
        var tableHtml = $(table).prop('outerHTML');

        // Create a Blob with the table HTML
        var blob = new Blob([tableHtml], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });

        // Create a data URI for the Blob
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create a temporary link element
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;

        // Set the download attribute and filename
        link.download = 'myExcelFile.xls';
        // Append the link to the document
        document.body.appendChild(link);

        // Trigger a click on the link to start the download
        link.click();

        // Remove the link from the document
        document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```